# Instagram api redirect uri pattern(regex)

Tags: instagram-api

Instagram auth api require valid redirect URIs.

But I want to use redirect uri like this
`http://myhost/{userId}/mypath` and this uri can't modify.
`{userId}` is variable.

Is it possible using redirect uri with variable uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `user-id` as url param and then construct the actual uri after redirect.

set your `redirect_uri` in instagram:

```
http://myhost/user
```

use your `redirect_uri` like this for login:

```
http://myhost/user?userid={userId}
```

on your server, redirect to above url to this:

```
http://myhost/{userId}/mypath
```

Comment: It is very inconvenience. T.T Thank you.